# Correct way to update Admin favicon

Tags: admin

What is the correct way to update the admin favicon? I assume copying over skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The correct location for the Admin favicon is indeed "skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico".

You can confirm this by viewing your Admin page's source code and you'll see something like this:-

```
<link rel="icon" href="{BASE URL}/skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{BASE URL}/skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Please make sure to clear your Magento cache and browser cache after you change it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes location of admin favicon icon occupies here `skin/adminhtml/default/default/favicon.ico`, unless you are not using any custom theme for admin side and it uses another `favicon.ico`.

So you can replace this default `favicon.ico` with yours. But make sure it also should name as `favicon.ico`

This is because, the favicon for admin side is included through this template `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\head.phtml` as like this

```
<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('favicon.ico') ?>" type="image/x-icon"/>
```

So if you want to give another name for your favicon or need to put to any other folder, you can do it here.

Comment: So it's not best practice to override the admin theme to update the favicon?

Comment: No editing a core file is not at all a good practice. You can copy the content of that file and create another template and paste content there and then through layout update you can direct `head` block to your template. That is the proper way. But if I was in your position, I will first change the name of default icon to something else and put custom favicon with a name `favicon.ico`. If I really need to edit the name of file, then I will directly edit the described file. I will not make it complicated :)

Comment: So there is no admin theme inheritance? it's not correct to make a new theme which would override the default image?